# objective c class as message argument

Tags: objective-c, class, cocos2d-iphone, arguments, scene

Is it possible to pass an objective c class (or maybe the notation is interface?) as message argument? Something like this:

```
-(void) f:(Class) c
{
  [c message];
}
```

To be more specific I want to call the following line:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionCrossFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[SceneDefence scene]]];
```

But I want SceneDefence to be a variable. I want to be able to call either SceneDefence or SceneAttack. The next scene will be stored in an instance variable in the init method, to later be used when the scene shall be changed.

Comment: Why not just pass an `id` instead?

Comment: OR why not just pass in the right scene, instead of the scene's class?

Comment: The scene is in cocos2d for some reason a class method. Is it possible to do that anyways? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you had it correct, you just need to call the class method [`class`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/class).

```
-(void) f:(Class) c
{
    [c message]; //message will need to be a class method
}

...
   [myclass f:[SceneDefence class]];
```

Comment: @Yuji Thanks, hard to break the habit considering all the other languages I use call them static :)

Comment: Ah, I did not call in a correct way, by using a class message! Thanks!